# Can Not Install JStock on Ubuntu (zorin 7)

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

Trying to install Jstock on a Linux Ubuntu Box. As a new user trying to install this product. I have received this error after following instruction - on to a Ubuntu (Zorin7) system.

#### Instructions

How to install JStock in Linux?

```
user@ubuntu804desktop:~$ cd ~
user@ubuntu804desktop:~$ wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/jstock/jstock-1.0.7i-bin.zip
user@ubuntu804desktop:~$ unzip jstock-1.0.7i-bin.zip
user@ubuntu804desktop:~$ cd jstock/
user@ubuntu804desktop:~/jstock$ chmod 755 jstock.sh
user@ubuntu804desktop:~/jstock$ ./jstock.sh
```

This is the error after imputing  - `cd jstock` it returned the following:-

```
:~/jstock$ /jstock$ chmod 755 jstock.sh
bash: /jstock$: No such file or directory
:~/jstock$ ls
config  database  docs  extra  jstock.jar  jstock.sh  lib
```

Can you please advise?

Comment: Can we get that list as `ls -l`?

Answer (score 0):

Given the error you're encountering it looks like you're missing `bash` on your system. Can you confirm that it's in fact installed? One of these commands should show this:

```
$ type bash
bash is /usr/bin/bash

$ locate -b bash |grep '/bin/bash'
/usr/bin/bash
```

If you look at the top of the script, `jstock.sh` it's looking for `bash` here, `/bin/bash`. You could workaround the issue by attempting to run `jstock.sh` like this instead:

```
$ bash jstock.sh
```

In any case when I ran `./jstock.sh` the application ran as expected.

[image: ss #!]

Comment: Thank you for the reply once i found out i had to set a password my appologies for the delay in responce.

Comment: Reply to answer as follows :-  $ locate -b bash |grep '/bin/bash'
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bashbug

Comment: @Londonman - were you able to run the script using `bash jstock.sh`?

Comment: Sorry No Change still the same Result - $ jstock.sh
jstock.sh: command not found

Comment: @Londonman - not sure if you saw my other comment, can we get a `ls -l` of the `jstock` directory? Also do you have Zorin 7 32-bit or 64-bit?